# Prove: $R(A+B) \subset R(B)+R(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove: $R(A+B) \subset R(B)+R(B)$

If it's not clear $R(A)$ is the the row-space of $A$.

Let $(A+B)_i$ the $i$-th row of $(A+B)$. We can write it as a linear combination of $A$ and $B$.

Indeed: $$(A+B)_i = 1\cdot A_i + 1\cdot B_i$$

So far I've showed that $R(A+B) \subseteq R(A) + R(B)$

How to show $\subset$?

Comment: The inclusion is not strict if for example $A=0$. Your confusion might be due to misinterpretation of the symbol $\subset$. Some authors use the symbol $\subset$ also to indicate a weak inclusion.

Comment: So, is my proof right and sufficient?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems reasonable.  By definition, $R(A+B)$ is the span of the row vectors in $A+B$.  You've shown that this spanning subset also belong to $R(A)+R(B)$, which implies $R(A+B)$ is a subspace of $R(A)+R(B)$.

It's not true in general that $R(A+B) \subsetneq R(A)+R(B)$.  Some counterexamples are: (a) when $A+B$ is a square matrix with full rank, or (b) when $A=\alpha B$ for some scalar $\alpha$.